# Dataframe creating new columns with new names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, apply

I have a dataframe like this

```
   Type
1   3
2   5
3   7
4   1
5   8
```

What i need is to add a column with the name of the Type and 0/1 input.
for example:

```
  Type    Type3   Type5   Type7  Type8  
1   3       1       0       0      0    
2   5       0       1       0      0    
3   7       0       0       1      0    
4   3       1       0       0      0    
5   8       0       0       0      1
```

I tried,

```
for i in range(10):
      if df['Type']  == i:
         df ['Type'+'i'] = 1
      else:
         df['Type'+'i'] = 0
```

but it did not work. Thx for help.

Comment: `df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.Type).add_prefix('Type'))`

Comment: you should also have `Type1` in your output